# Trying to print multiple files from directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to print multiple files in a list from my directory.
The only part that needs fixing is the print(file) line. This part only shows one .txt file even thought I have more than one text file. 
This is my code:

```
for file in os.listdir("C:\NoteQuick"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(file)#This part only shows one 1 txt file 
        file_name = raw_input("Enter the file name with the extension")
        s = open((file_name), "a")
        newdata = raw_input("Enter new data to be saved")
        s.write(str(newdata))
        s.close()
```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code not work like expected? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: this snippet doesn't do what the title suggests.

Comment: My code does work but when it tries to print the files in my directory, it only shows one file even though I have more than one .txt file.

Comment: did you also try `import glob glob.glob('C:\NoteQuick\*.txt')`

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work.

Comment: Thad, what your program says is, "For each file in the directory, print first file and ask user to input a file name. Then open the file name they specify, append their input and close the file. Then print the next file name" You need to move everything after your print line two tabs to the left

Comment: If `print(file)` only shows one file then that means that line of code is only executed once. That means that the `if` condition is true only once, perhaps because the `for` loop executes only once or the condition is true for only one iteration of the loop. Or perhaps this code is surrounded, somewhere, by a `try...except` that suppresses an exception that is raised.  Or perhaps you are looking at the prompt for input after the first file is listed and wondering why more files aren't listed (because it is waiting for input to proceed)

Answer (score 2):

Run these two programs and you'll understand how to fix yours.

**Hint:** Python uses indentation to structure program.

First:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
        raw_input("enter something")
```

Second:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
raw_input("enter something")
```